# Removing one Duplicate value from a String in Java 8 using lambdas

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have to *remove* a duplicate value from a `String`.

But first I have to *filter* the given value that needs to be deleted. And if it's a duplicate, return a *new String* with first *duplicated value* removed. And I want to do this using lambdas.

**Example**.

*Input* (filter the value: `"A"`)

```
String input = "A, A, C";
```

*Expected output*

```
"A, C"
```

But if I have this.

*Input* (filter a value different to `"A"`)

```
String input = "A, A, C";
```

*Expected output*

```
"A, A, C"
```

I.e. if the given *filter-value* is a duplicate, like "A", which is encountered in the string multiple times, then its *first occurrence* has to be *removed*. Otherwise, *the same string* should be returned.

The white spaces and commas has to be considered in the output too.

I have been tried this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mercado = "A, B, A";
       mercado = mercado.replaceAll("\\b(A)\\b(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "");
       System.out.println( mercado );
    }
}
```

But the output is:  `, B, A`

And I have to remove that white space and that comma in front.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of *filter a value distinct to: "A"*? And please share what have you tried.

Comment: a value distinct to: "A" means that if i try to filter another String diferent to the String "A" the program does not need to delete it from the given String, in this case the given String is: "A, A, C"

Comment: I.e. if the given value is a duplicate, like `"A"`, which is encountered in the string multiple times, then its first occurrence has to be removed. Otherwise, the method should return the same string, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, that is the way

Comment: Your two inputs are the same but you expected output is different.  Please edit the question to clarify.  And what if you had `"A, B, A, B, A, B"`?

Comment: @WJS Input is not a single string, but two strings. Take a look at the couple of comment above yours.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko  Well, I read the comments and it doesn't change the fact that each string in the question looks like a single string.  Both inputs are `"A, A, C"`.  And like you pointed out in a recent question, clarifications should be made in the question, not in the comments. :)

Comment: @WJS Below the first input string OP specified *filter the value: "A"*, below the second - *filter a value distinct to "A"* (which definitely should be rephrased). Also, in the comment OP confirmed that they want  to **remove the first occurrence** of so-called *filter value* if *filter value* is a duplicate, and otherwise return the same *input string*.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko so the “different input” that yields to different result expectations is something that does not even appear in the OP’s solution attempt?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your goal correctly, you need a method that expects two string arguments.

And depending on the number of occurrences of the second string in the *first string* the method will return either the ***first string intact*** (*if the target value is unique or not present in the first string*), or will generate a ***new string*** by removing the first occurrence of the target value (*the second string*).

This problem can be addressed in the following steps:

- Create a *list* by splitting the given string.
- Count the number of occurrences of the target value.
- If the count is `<= 1` (*i.e. value is unique, or not present at all*) return the same string.
- Otherwise remove the *target value* from the *list*.
- Combine list elements into a string.

It might be implemented like this:

```
public static String removeFirstIfDuplicate(String source, String target) {
    List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(source.split("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}]+")));

    long targetCount = sourceList.stream()
        .filter(str -> str.equals(target))
        .count();

    if (targetCount <= 1) {
        return source;
    }    
    sourceList.remove(target);

    return sourceList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeFirstIfDuplicate("A, A, C", "A"));
    System.out.println(removeFirstIfDuplicate("A, A, C", "C"));
}
```

**Output**

```
A, C
A, A, C
```